# VS Code: wrap with HTML tag for multiple selection regions

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when I have multiple selection regions and I try to use the feature of wrapping with a HTML tag, it only wraps the first selection region. I've tried both "Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation" and "Wrap in HTML Tags" - both only wrap the first selection region.

In Sublime Text this worked beautifully. Is there any way to get this working in VS Code as well?

UPDATE 2018:
This is has now been fixed, it works as expected natively.

Comment: Maybe work similar if you install this extension in Vs Code: **[HtmlTagWrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradgashler.htmltagwrap)**